# Total reputation chart confusion

Tags: support, top-users, total-reputation

This total reputation chart found at [Top Users Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) is confusing me:

[image: totalrepchart]

For example, where it says 5,000+ total rep, does it actually mean **5,000 to 9,999 rep**? If not then that means some of those 7,205 users are also included in higher brackets as well.

This makes a big difference so I just wanted to eliminate my confusion.

**EDIT:**  Here is another example of why I care to know the difference. If 5,000+ literally means any user with 5k or more rep then that means I have to do some calculations to figure out exactly how many users have 5,000-9,999 reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [The lowest rank in the leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/565534?sort=reputationchange#565534) == the total number of people
   in the leagues == 107,175
2. This is the number of people listed in the 200+ bracket
3. This means the 200+ bracket includes all people from 200 up, not just 200 to 499
4. By extension, the 5,000+ bracket includes all people from 5000 up, not just 5000 to 9999

As far as your calculation is concerned, no, you would just have to subtract the bracket immediately above, not all the ones above it. That is to say, n<sub>5000-9999</sub> == n<sub>5000+</sub> - n<sub>10000+</sub> == 7205 - 3269

Answer (score 2):

That 94 users having 100,000+ rep are a **subset** of the 295 users having 50,000+ rep.

Answer (score 1):

50000+ means 50000 to infinity, in line with common usage.

You can (currently) verify this on [page 10](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=10) where user #295 in the ranking is today indeed the first person with over 50000 rep, as listed in the chart.

It's easier than you said to calculate an individual band, since they're all cumulative. 5000-9999 is 7205-3269=3936 users.

Comment: So the 94 users with 100,000+ rep are also counted in every other bracket?

Comment: @AustinHenley: yes, they are.

Comment: Yup. That's the way it works.