# Adding a button to improve navigation through the questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, pagination

At the bottom of the [Questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) there are some buttons for changing page, i.e. You can find something like:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ... [93376] [next]
```

Since the number of question is high, if I want to reach a page in the middle I have to click on the `[next]` button thousand of times.

For this reason I think it could be useful to have, next to the `[next]` button, another button like `[next 100]` or `[next 1000]` or `[go to page ...]`.

Do you agree?

Comment: Why would you ever want to go to a specific page though? On SO the page order is pretty useless, and meaningless to boot as it constantly shifts

Comment: As in the comment to the @Doorknob answer, I haven't a particular motivation. I supposed it could be useful i.e. if (for some reason) I want to get the questions asked 1 year ago. But since the lack of reasons, and the "change the URL" workaround, I am now convinced that it could be not so useful.

Comment: This would have been handy when answering [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160587/total-reputation-chart-confusion)

Comment: One reason is to try to reduce the number of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=(THE_PAGE_NUMBER)&sort=newest
```

But why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is no particular motivation. Just, I supposed it could be useful. Anyway I didn't think about changing the URL before. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The best reason I could see you might want to browse to the middle is if you are scanning for questions with a specific vote count, or in a specific range of votes, and much of that you can accomplish with a search, for example:

> [Search for XML-tagged questions with a score in the range of 22 to 45](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml%5D%20score:22-45%20is:question)

This search leaves you with just 180 (as of this writing) questions and 4 to 12 pages (depending on your questions per page setting).  Once filtered down, there is much less for you to have to browse and less of a need to scan through a large number of pages of questions, or to manual enter the page in the URL to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think that would add unneeded clutter.  It's rare that I want to go to a specific page that isn't the first, last, previous, or next page.  If I want to go to a page in the middle I can edit the URL.